# How can I improve this query in postgresql? Its taking more than 48 houers already

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I do have the following query and I'm running it against a postgresql db which has more than 10M entries in table `account_message` and 1M entries in table `message`.

Postgresql is in Version `PostgreSQL 11.12, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit`

Is there any way to make this query faster because it takes more than 2 days already and did not finish yet.

```
DELETE FROM account_message WHERE message_id in
(SELECT t2.id FROM message t2 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM customer t1 WHERE 
t1.username = t2.username));
```

Table `account_message` has the following columns:

```
id (bigint)(primary key)
user_id (bigint)
message_id (bigint)
isRead (boolean)
isDeleted (boolean)
```

Table `message` has the following columns:

```
id (bigint)(primary key)
username (character varying)(255)
text (character varying)(10000)
details(character varying)(1000)
status(integer)
```

Table `customer` has the following columns:

```
username (character varying)(255)(primary key)
type(character varying)(500)
details(character varying)(10000)
status(integer)
active(boolean)
```

This did the trick for me and also makes it much faster.

```
DELETE FROM account_message WHERE message_id IN (
  SELECT m.id FROM message m
    LEFT JOIN customer c ON m.username = c.username
    WHERE c.username IS NULL LIMIT 1000)
```

Comment: Does your tables have appropriate indices, namely on `message_id` and `username`?

Comment: How can I check this? For example with pgAdmin.

Comment: I would try something like this: `select * from pg_indexes where lower(tablename) in ('account_message', 'message', 'customer');`

Comment: Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info) then [edit] your question to show us your table definitions and query plans.

Comment: Try to convert the `IN (SELECT ...)` into an `EXISTS (SELECT ...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to improve this by

1. getting rid of your dependent subquery, and
2. doing it in batches.

Try this to get a batch of one thousand message ids to delete. `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE col IS NULL` is a way to write `WHERE NOT EXISTS` without a dependent subqiery.

```sql
SELECT m.id 
  FROM message m
  LEFT JOIN customer c ON m.username = c.username
 WHERE c.username IS NULL
 LIMIT 1000
```

Then, use the subquery in a statement. Repeat the statement until it deletes no rows.

```
DELETE 
  FROM account_message
 WHERE message_id IN (
      SELECT m.id 
        FROM message m
        LEFT JOIN customer c ON m.username = c.username
       WHERE c.username IS NULL
       LIMIT 1000)
```

Doing this in batches of 1000 helps performance: it splits your operation into multiple reasonably sized database transactions.

Comment: When doing this in batches of 1000, when are they exactly executed? I do run this in a flyway script. So usually every script like this one here is only executed once. Do I have to manage this by myself?

Answer (score 0):

First, try to optimize the select inside brakets.  Something like:

```
DELETE FROM account_message WHERE message_id in
(
  select t2.id message t2
  left join customer t1 on (t1.username = t2.username)
  where t2.username is NULL
)
```

Comment: Why should that be faster?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  elimination of dependent subqueries has the potential to make it faster.

Comment: @O.Jones PostgreSQL usually optimizes `NOT EXISTS` into an anti-join. In my experience it often outperforms `IN (SELECT ...)`.